# Is there a practical way to use IronPython entirely within the VS 2k10 IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ironpython

I've looked through the existing threads on IronPython and IDEs without finding an answer.

If I don't need to support Python 3, is there a practical way to do IronPython development fully inside the VS 2k10 IDE like I used to with FORTRAN.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IronPython 2.7 includes VS 2010 support - it's still only a beta but if you download and install it there's an option to install VS support.  That includes a project system, intellisense, a REPL window, object browsing, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is no. I have had bad luck with IronPython, especially when native modules are in play (even when they're part of the standard library). However, there is [IronPython Studio](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/), which is built on VS2008 and [IPyDD](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/IPyDD). I don't think .NET is ready for Python yet :(

Comment: Ironpython Studio has not been updated since 1.1  Do not use.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2008 No.

VS2010  The extension module is fine, but it does not allow you to compile to an exe from within VS2010.

I prefer Sharpdevelop 3.5 or later.  I don't know if #develop supports FORTRAN.NET though.